# Confirmation modal for sensitive actions

Tags: confirmation, cancel

I would like to know which of these practices is considered as the best.
A user of my website has the possibility of emptying its shopping basket.

Should I :

- ask for confirmation with a modal ?
- let him do, but allow a rollback right after

Comment: I'm a fan of Amazon's _undo_ -- although I'm not sure if it's an option when the basket is completely cleared.

Answer (score 2):

This is some sort of [deleting things](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49991/should-yes-delete-it-be-red-or-green/64829#64829).

My solution for deleting things is a button with a trash icon which opens a little popover. I think this is a good solution because:

- **no disturbing dialog**, everyone hates confirmation dialogs!
- confirmation is required. no accidential clicks
- user has only to read two words, **no annoying question**
- red color indicates that it is really deleted
- **minimum of mouse and eye movement**
- minimum of space wasted
- no context switch

[image: screenshot## Heading ##]

Answer (score 0):

Now think about you goals against the user goals.

You can add a modal confirmation for "empty a shopping basket" thinking that your goal is to prevent users from emptying the basket, you can prevent placing the modal, which would bring the user to rethink every action if you really want to empty the cart. 
On the other hand it can be a way to generate friction and lead to frustration.

Initially I suggest you show a modal on mass removal product, but not for the elimination of individual products and also allow the action to reverse (as in the picture)

[image: Revert closed tab]

Also try to show the last products viewed to allow the user to find potential removed products

[image: las products viewed]