# Yes and No buttons are both positive. Is it okay for these to both be green, implying 'success'?

Tags: forms, buttons, confirmation, modal-windows

This is similar to [Should "Yes, delete it" be red, or green?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49991/should-yes-delete-it-be-red-or-green/49996#49996), but I feel it isn't quite a duplicate as my situation is different.

I have a form which looks like this:

[image: Form Example 1]

When a user enters text into the input field, the green add button (<kbd>+</kbd>) appears. Clicking this button enables the submit button (<kbd>Update</kbd>) and allows the user to add more items. This creates something like this:

[image: Form Example 2]

If a user clicks on the <kbd>Update</kbd> button after entering text into the input field without first clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button, a modal window appears asking whether they want to submit the form with that not-added input included or not.

This introduces a situation whereby both buttons with text "Yes" and "No" are positive, as regardless of which one gets clicked, the form will be submitted anyway:

[image: Modal Example]

I realise I could just disable the <kbd>Update</kbd> button if the not-added input field has text entered, but I feel forcing the user to clear the text manually before submitting the form (if they've changed their mind, for instance) may be counter-productive.

Is it okay to have two green 'success' buttons for the opposing choices, or does this make the options confusing? Should this be handled in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this answer may not relate to the titled question, it does relate to your particular case.

I find the modal dialog itself very awkward, regardless of the color of the buttons.

> When a user enters text into the input field, the green add button (+)
>   appears. Clicking this button enables the submit button (Update) and
>   allows the user to add more items. This creates something like this:

I think this is the source of all your problems.

Why not have the `Update` button enabled as soon as valid text is entered into the textbox, and the user should only press the `+` button if they want to add *another* item?

Comment: Definitely a better option.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is not what color to make those buttons but rather why is this message needed in the first place?

I have a similar implementation of adding emails to a report list and the add/remove buttons are always visible. It is understood that if something was typed then yes, it wants to be saved. Any empty/blank fields are simply ignored and if the page is refreshed then you only see boxes with values and none of the empties.

[image]