# Button text for 'Are you sure you want to cancel this order' alert?

Tags: buttons, checkout, actions, ordering, cancel

I'm working on an eCommerce site where we're implementing a feature that allows the user to cancel an order (of physical goods) that's in transit.

On the line item (parcel level) the user can 'cancel this parcel'. 
On Click, I want to display a warning along the lines of: Are you sure you want to cancel this parcel? This cannot be undone.

Here's the bit I'm struggling with. 
There should be a positive Yes, I want to cancel, and a negative, No I do not want to cancel.

It feels like I've got to be cognisant of the word 'cancel' in this solution.

The cancel of the cancel order action might cause confusion unless I get it crystal clear.

Any ideas on the button text for the two options?  I want to keep the button actions super clear, easy to understand and not too long.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49991/should-yes-delete-it-be-red-or-green

Comment: (1) "Cancel" usually means "do nothing, and leave things unchanged." Choose a different word for that. (2) People don't read what you want them to read, so the button labels have to say what they do, rather than "Yes" and "No." So: "Delete Order" and "Cancel" maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be really clear, you could go with essentially how you described it to us. A more conversational button naming scheme. 
"Yes, cancel it" and "No, don't cancel it". Adding the 'it' reinforces the idea that you're cancelling the parcel, rather than the dialogue. Alternatively, 'it' could be substituted for 'parcel', with other appropriate modifiers.

I also think that a simpler "Yes" and "No" would work well directly under "Would you like to cancel your parcel?". It really is a yes or no question, so as long as you're making what the question and answers are visually clear, it should retain that clarity to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple - Are you sure
Button Text - Yes Cancel
Button Text - No dont cancel

Comment: Could you give a bit more information on why this is a good solution?